# onPanResponderRelease not working on android devices

Tags: android, ios, react-native

When i am using panResponders on iOS devices it works properly but same code when i run on android devices it is not working as expected. Code is as below

```
componentWillMount() {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

        onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
            return true;
        },
        onPanResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => {
            console.log('getting on android');
            return false;
        },
        onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
            console.log('getting here')
            return true;
        },
        onPanResponderTerminate : (evt, gestureState) => {
            console.log('gets');
        }
    });
}
```

Also my scrollView snippet is as below.

```
<ScrollView
      ref={ref => this.myScroll = ref }
      {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>
```

Comment: did you tried with onPanResponderEnd ?

Answer (score 0):

To get it working properly use `onPanResponderEnd` instead of `onPanResponderRelease`.

Also if we still want to use `onPanResponderRelease` then we should allow termination request by:

```
onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => true
```